# Why is font rendering in Document Viewer poor?

Tags: display, fonts

I've just noticed that the font rendering in Elementary's Document Viewer app seems a little sub-bar with chopped or truncated edges making reading a little uncomfortable.

Having read about Infinality font rendering, I'm curious as to what rendering Elementary currently uses. Though, I haven't experienced this problem in other apps.

Is there a way I can improve font rendering for the pdf viewer? I know the embedded font isn't an issue as I have viewed it on another computer. Thanks!

(p.s. view the attached img at 100%)[image]

Comment: elementary OS is using GNOME's `evince` to display PDF files. Please try to display your file in an Ubuntu session if possible. I suppose the PDF file to be the problem. Didn't have any rendering problems here yet.